# How to integrate API.AI on Ionic App that uses Typescript?

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, dialogflow-es

I'm new to API.AI and Ionic and would like to integrate them to create a chatbot style application.

Has anyone been successful on integrating these? Would appreciate if you can point me on the right track.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, anyone been successful on this?

Answer (score 0):

API.AI has a /query API that allows you to query you API.AI agent with a user's request and get back the response from your API.AI agent: https://api.ai/docs/reference/agent/query

You could create an Ionic App that uses [API.AI](https://api.ai)'s /query API to make a chat interface powered by your API.AI agent.

Comment: Thanks matthewayne. Figure out need to also setup webhooks to call external API. Thanks for your guidance.